# get model from List of a model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, model

Is there a way to get the specific items from the list of a model without using a foreach of the list? like if you return a `List<model>` holding a model with a few differnt items to specifically call those item.

Comment: You mean access them by index?

Comment: There's a ton of ways to access items in a list without iterating through it with `foreach`. Have you looked at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4.aspx)?

Comment: In the immortal words of Einstein... Huh? Can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# LambdaExpression, like this:

```
var yourModel = modelList.Where(x => x.Id = 12).Select(x).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of a specific item that's within your list then you can use LINQ to return those items, for example:

```
var customerNames = customersList.Select(customer => customer.Name);
```

This would give you a string collection with all of your customer names equal to the amount that was in your original list.

Or if you would like to retrieve a number of different items from your model list then you may want to look into creating a class specifically for stripping out those items, for example:

```
public class CustomerContactDetails
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}

...

var contactDetails = customersList.Select(customer => new CustomerContactDetails { Address = customer.Address, Email = customer.Email, Telephone = customer.Telephone });
```